# Set height of cell equal to the label content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with several customCells and therefor i can't use `estimatedRowHeight`. However in this cell i need to set the row height equal to the content of the label inside the cell. However it does not seem to show all the text.

I've started by setting cosntraints

[image]

Then in cell subclass i set font height

```
descLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
```

Then i create the calculation func

```
func calculateHeightForString(inString:String) -> CGFloat
{
    let messageString = inString
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)]

    let attrString:NSMutableAttributedString? = NSMutableAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)
    attrString!.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString!.length))
    let rect:CGRect = attrString!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width-24,CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context:nil )//hear u will get nearer height not the exact value
    let requredSize:CGRect = rect


    return requredSize.height  //to include button's in your tableview

}
```

Setting the height for section 1

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        return 160.0/320.0 * tableView.bounds.width
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        return self.calculateHeightForString("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also th") + 24
    } else {
        return 100
    }
}
```

Result where it does not show everything

[image]

Comment: Check what is the cell height for 1 liner is. If it is the same as above then constraint seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have setup your constraints correctly and your  app's deployment target is >= iOS 8 you can use the automatic row height calculation. therefore you have to do the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

where **44** should be some kind of average rowheight. then you do not have to implement the methods `estimatedRowHeight` and `heightForRow` at all...

you can also implement `heightForRow` and do something like the following:

```
// if cell is of kind textview cell
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
// else
return some static value
```

Comment: Well as i mentioned it does not seem to work in my case since i have multiple cell subclasses where rest is static heights

Comment: in that case you **can** implement `heightForRow` and return automatic dimension for cells of kind _textviewcell_...

Answer (score 0):

From your String it looks like last line is missing. This can be due to negative constraint on the bottom (shows -4 in the attached pic). Try changing it to something positive.